# Capitalizing letters. R equivalent of excel "PROPER" function

Tags: r, string, capitalization, toupper, tolower

Colleagues,

I'm looking at a data frame resembling the extract below:

```
Month   Provider Items
January CofCom   25
july    CofCom   331
march   vobix    12
May     vobix    0
```

I would like to capitalise first letter of each word and lower the remaining letters for each word. This would result in the data frame resembling the one below:

```
Month   Provider Items
January Cofcom   25
July    Cofcom   331
March   Vobix    12
May     Vobix    0
```

In a word, I'm looking for R's equivalent of the *[ROPER](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/qt/8124_proper.htm)* function available in the MS Excel.

Comment: See `capwords` function in `?tolower` help page

Comment: There is a `capwords` function defined in the Examples section of `?tolower` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question is about an equivalent of Excel `PROPER` and the (former) accepted answer is based on:

```
proper=function(x) paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(x, 2)))
```

It might be worth noting that:

```
proper("hello world")
## [1] "Hello world"
```

Excel `PROPER` would give, instead,   "Hello World". For 1:1 mapping with Excel see @Matthew Plourde.

If what you actually need is to set only the first character of a string to upper-case, you might also consider the shorter and slightly faster version:

```
proper=function(s) sub("(.)", ("\\U\\1"), tolower(s), pe=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 32):

With regular expressions:

```
x <- c('woRd Word', 'Word', 'word words')
gsub("(?<=\\b)([a-z])", "\\U\\1", tolower(x), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "Word Word"  "Word"       "Word Words"
```

`(?<=\\b)([a-z])` says look for a lowercase letter preceded by a word boundary (e.g., a space or beginning of a line). `(?<=...)` is called a "look-behind" assertion. `\\U\\1` says replace that character with it's uppercase version. `\\1` is a back reference to the first group surrounded by `()` in the pattern. See `?regex` for more details.

If you only want to capitalize the first letter of the first word, use the pattern `"^([a-z])` instead.

Comment: This is the actual answer. I urge the questioner to reconsider their check.

Comment: Is the back reference necessary?  Wouldn't this give the same result?  `gsub("(\\b[a-z])", "\\U\\1", tolower(xx), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: This does not work well for all languages as this also capitalizes letters after special characters (such as umlauts).

Answer (score 11):

Another method uses the stringi package.  The stri_trans_general function appears to lower case all letters other than the initial letter.

```
require(stringi)
x <- c('woRd Word', 'Word', 'word words')
stri_trans_general(x, id = "Title")
[1] "Word Word"  "Word"       "Word Words"
```

Comment: For future visitors: stringi has a function called `stri_trans_totitle` which does the same thing. Not sure if that existed at the time of this answer.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think there is one, but you can easily write it yourself

```
(dat <- data.frame(x = c('hello', 'frIENds'),
                   y = c('rawr','rulZ'),
                   z = c(16, 18)))
#         x    y  z
# 1   hello rawr 16
# 2 frIENds rulZ 18

proper <- function(x)
  paste0(toupper(substr(x, 1, 1)), tolower(substring(x, 2)))


(dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x)
  if (is.numeric(x)) x else proper(x)),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

#         x    y  z
# 1   Hello Rawr 16
# 2 Friends Rulz 18

str(dat)
# 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ x: chr  "Hello" "Friends"
#   $ y: chr  "Rawr" "Rulz"
#   $ z: num  16 18
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It's such a nice thing that should be part of the base :)

Comment: Just one word of caution that available numeric column in the function was changed to factor after I applied this function, which messed up the chart a little so I had to make it numeric again.

Comment: @Konrad that that case, I would, `data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x else proper(x)))` or something similar

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very useful solution. I'm wondering whether it would be sensible to move `if(is.numeric` part to the function itself.

Comment: you could do that, too. you could also expand the function to handle different classes in different ways